# get inner HTML element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html hierarchy:

```
...
<div class="custom-img-wrapper">
<a target="_blank" class="link-d" href="#"><img class="custom-below-img" src="some source"></a>
<h3><a target="_blank" class="link-d" href="#">some text</a></h3>
</div>

<div class="custom-img-wrapper">
<a target="_blank" class="link-d" href="#"><img class="custom-below-img" src="some source"></a>
<h3><a target="_blank" class="link-d" href="#">some text</a></h3>
</div>
...
```

and i am going over the links with this for loop :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("link-d");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].href = link;
}
```

now my question is how can i save the `src` of the image which is inside the link, so i'll get somwthing like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("link-d");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var link_of_image_inside_node = x[i].????
    x[i].href = link;
}
```

i know i can loop over the `custom-below-image` but that's not what i need, and im looking for a pure JavaScript no jQuery solution any idea? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` tags first child element is image then

```
var link_of_image_inside_node = x[i].firstChild.src;
```

OR

```
var link_of_image_inside_node = x[i].children[0].src; //ignores all the text before img tag
```

where `x[i]` is the anchor element

Comment: `firstChild` can return TextNode also

Comment: @Grundy then the `x[i].children[0].src` will be handy

Comment: methinks, this can be noted in answer :-)

Comment: @Grundy done however you can also edit any answer if you feel like it :)

Comment: I know :-) i just notice that first variant can return wrong result :-) solution you suggest self